# CSS Anchoring Text to Image Corner

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive design were images scales according to the viewport, depending on whichever width or height of the viewport restricts the image, it never exceeds the viewport.

This was quite easy to achieve, but now I have the issue that the left-aligned title over the images doesn't of course follow the center'd image, but instead sticks by the page margin. I tried experimenting with all sorts of different calculated padding and other junk, but so far I can't figure it out.

What I'd ideally would like to do is to scale a box according to the viewport and center-align that box, and then have a full width image inside the box, and the left aligned title above it.

Here's what I've got so far, excuse the crude CSS.

Code:

```css
/* Create 1 column that floats */

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Add a card effect for articles */

.card {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  padding: 1vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: none;
}

.card h3 {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 0vw;
  margin-top: 0vw;
}

.card img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 95vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="page.html"><button type="button" class="card">
                <h3>Image Title</h3>
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" 
             alt="Image Title">
            </button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use a `<button>` tag as wrapper?

Comment: The short answer is; because I want the whole thing to be clickable. If this is the correct way, I'm not sure.

Comment: If my answer solves your question please mark it as correct so other people can see it has alredy been answered

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you can change your HTML structure and you're open to use a more semantic HTML structure you should go with the following.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card figure {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <figure onclick="buttonClickBehaviourFunction()">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/eee">
  </figure>
</div>
```

I've also added the `onclick="buttonClickBehaviourFunction()"` attribute so you can mimic a button behavour aswell.

**Now a little weird hack**

I do not recommend this approach as it is not semantic (you will have to style it on your own).

```css
.figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin: auto;
}

h3 {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="figure">
  <h3>Caption</h3>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/eee">
</button>
```

You can use this if you absolutely need to have a `<button>` tag and you can't change your HTML structure. If none of those apply, the only advantage of this method is that you don't need another wrapper.

Notice that if you change `<button>` to `<div>` in the above example it will not work as it relies on the fact that `<button>` is a  **replaced element**, and so its size is defined by content width, just like inline elements, but its margin are calculated like block elements, so you can use `margin:auto`.

[CSS Spec on 10.3.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins):

> The used value of 'width' is determined as for inline replaced elements. Then the rules for non-replaced block-level elements are applied to determine the margins.

Anyway, I was just sharing what I've found while looking for how to solve this without changing HTML structure. Please go with the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `h3` and the `img` in a `div` and center that. By the way, float:center doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried this out but I can't get it to work as expected, the H3 title is always 1.5 vw to the right of the left margin...

Comment: It should be visible in the inspector, what causes the `1.5vw` offset. When you find that, reset it to 0. `button{padding:0}`